# Are Table-Valued or Scalar Functions available for use inside of a View?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, sql-view

I've created a `TVF` and a `Scalar` in `SQL Server 2008` to use inside of a `View` I am creating.  The view does not seem to have the ability to see or use the function and I am unsure if my error is permission based or if it is entirely not possible to call a `TVF` from within a `View`?

The error I get in SSMS is `Invalid Object Name dbo.TwoYearColumnsWithNulls'`

Here is the `TVF` I have created:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[TwoYearColumnsWithNulls]()
RETURNS @table TABLE( cols nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @startdate as varchar(max),@enddate as varchar(max);
    Set @startdate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())-1) as varchar(4))+'-01-01';
    Set @enddate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())) as varchar(4))+'-12-24';    

    WITH DateRange(dt) AS
            (
                SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startdate) dt
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(ww,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, @enddate)
            )
    INSERT INTO @table (cols) SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'isnull('+QUOTENAME((cast(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) as varchar(4)))+'-Week'+(cast(DATEPART(ww, dt) as varchar(2))))+', 0)' FROM DateRange
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        OPTION (maxrecursion 0);

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Here is a small snippet of the `View` Im trying to use it in.  The view does have a `PIVOT` in there as well, not sure if that matters?

```
CREATE VIEW [testdta].[TwoYearInventoryIssues]
AS
SELECT LIITM as ShortItemNumber, IMLITM as LongItemNumber, (SELECT cols FROM dbo.TwoYearColumnsWithNulls())
FROM
    (
        SELECT LIITM, IMLITM,.......
<SNIP>
```

---

**EDIT**

Per comments below, I did try using a `Scalar` function as well as a `TVF` to achieve the same result.  Both did not work providing the same error.  In case it helps, here is the `Scalar` function I tried:

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.TwoYearColumnsWithNullsScalar()
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @isnullcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @startdate as varchar(max),@enddate as varchar(max);
    Set @startdate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())-1) as varchar(4))+'-01-01';
    Set @enddate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())) as varchar(4))+'-12-24';    

    WITH DateRange(dt) AS
            (
                SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startdate) dt
                UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(ww,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, @enddate)
            )
    SELECT @isnullcols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'isnull('+QUOTENAME((cast(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) as varchar(4)))+'-Week'+(cast(DATEPART(ww, dt) as varchar(2))))+', 0)' FROM DateRange
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        OPTION (maxrecursion 0);

    RETURN  @isnullcols
END
```

Comment: Even if this is not related to your error, why are you using a table valued function as a scalar one?, does it always return just one row?

Comment: @Lamak - I did try both `Scalar` and `TVF` function and both had the same result.  The TVF was the last option I tried so it's what I put in the question.  It seems my `View` cannot see/use any type of function in the DB...

Comment: It can be that the schema in wich you are creating the view (`testdta`) can't see the functions that are on the `dbo` schema. Can you try creating you view on the same schema of your function?

Comment: Still no luck with the different schema in the `View`.  I do get results if I run this from a query window: `SELECT cols FROM testdta.TwoYearColumns()`